# Currencies at the same time

Tags: magento-1.8, currency

I need to  display 2 currencies at the same time (USD and BRL, both alreary configured in my magento backend) and I´d tried to follow this post ( [Two currencies at same time](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45890/two-currencies-at-same-time/54484#54484))  however I´m doing something wrong. Hope you can help me figure out that.

I´ve changed in line 7  `$rates = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getCurrencyRates  **for**    $rates = Mage::getModel('app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php')->getCurrencyRates(`

and

in line 15 ->getTranslation($code, 'nametocurrency');  **for** ->getTranslation($code, 'USD');

When I try to see the page I get the following error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getCurrencyRates() on a non-object in/home3/grupots/public_html/terrasantaviagens.com.br/lojavirtual/app/design/frontend/default/helloresponsive/template/catalog/product/price.phtmlon line 7

price.phtml directory that I´m changing the code= pp/design/frontend/default/helloresponsive/template/catalog/product/

Any ideas on what I´m doing wrong?

Follow entire code as asked:

At the begining of price.phtml

```
  <?php $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $currentCurrency = $store->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    $currencies = array();

    $codes = Mage::app()->getStore()->getAvailableCurrencyCodes(true);
    if (is_array($codes) && count($codes) > 1) {
        $rates = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getCurrencyRates(
            Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrency(),
            $codes
        );

        foreach ($codes as $code) {
            if (isset($rates[$code])) {
                $currencies[$code] = Mage::app()->getLocale()
                    ->getTranslation($code, 'USD');
            }
        }
    }

    foreach($currencies as $code => $value): 

    ?>

        <?php $store->setCurrentCurrency(null)->setCurrentCurrencyCode(strtoupper($code), false); ?>
        <?php if(strtoupper($code) != strtoupper($currentCurrency)) $this->setIdSuffix($this->getIdSuffix().'-'.strtolower($code)); ?>
```

At the end of price.phtml:

```
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php $store->setCurrentCurrency(null)->setCurrentCurrencyCode($currentCurrency); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
Mage::getModel('app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php')->getCurrencyRates
```

`directory/currency` is the module/model.  It looks like you were thinking that it was asking for "directory" and "currency" when in fact it's just looking for the module called directory and the model named currency.

Leave the original line as-is:

```
Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getCurrencyRates
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I just changed back the code to the original and now I get an error message: HTTP 503, any ideas?

Comment: Can you update your question with your entire code?

Comment: updated @seanbreeden